# Show that: $\sqrt{abcd}\le\left(\frac{a+b+c+d}{4}\right)^2$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

Assuming that $a,b,c,d$ are not negative,

How can one show that:

$$\sqrt{abcd}\le \left(\frac{a+b+c+d}{4}\right)^2$$

I tried this:

By $\text{AM}\ge \text{GM}$ we have $ab\le\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2$

Same for $cd$ so:

$$abcd\le\left(\frac{(a+b)(c+d)}{4}\right)^2$$

I'm stuck here

Comment: You're overcomplicating a simple problem. You see $\frac{a+b+c+d}{4}$, clearly you should just use AM-GM on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $a, b, c, d$ positive real numbers then we have 
$$AM=\frac{a+b+c+d}{4}$$
$$GM=\left(abcd\right)^{1/4}$$
We know that $AM\ge GM$ hence,
$$\frac{a+b+c+d}{4}\ge \left(abcd\right)^{1/4}$$
since, both the sides are positive hence taking squares as follows 
$$\left(\frac{a+b+c+d}{4}\right)^2\ge \left(abcd\right)^{2/4}$$
$$\left(\frac{a+b+c+d}{4}\right)^2\ge \left(abcd\right)^{1/2}$$
$$\sqrt{abcd}\le \left(\frac{a+b+c+d}{4}\right)^2$$

Answer (score 5):

This is one way to prove it:

$$\frac{a+b+c+d}{4}=\frac{\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{c+d}{2}}{2} \geq \frac{\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{cd}}{2} \geq \sqrt[4]{abcd}.$$